# How to use RippleView to create ripples?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, ripple

I am trying to create a ripple when my button is clicked by using the [RippleEffect project](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect), however every time I run the code the app crashes. How do I fix this? Alternatively, is there an easier way to get a ripple when a button is clicked? Please help if possible. Thank you!

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.andexert.library.RippleView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="95dp">

            // Button 1
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/name1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="95dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_border"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

            // TIME 1
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/name1"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:id="@+id/editText1" />

            // NAME 1
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="             "
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/name1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:cursorVisible="false" />
        </com.andexert.library.RippleView>

    </RelativeLayout> // End Left Side
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/124/material-design-for-all-android-versions/14200/rippledrawable#t=201611040354215769953

Comment: Show the logcat output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to check the [sample codes](https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView)

View that imitates Ripple Effect on click which was introduced in Android L.

For a working implementation, Have a look at the Sample Project - RippleViewExample

Include the library as local library project.

Include the RippleView widget in your layout.

In your onCreate method refer to the View and add 'OnClickListener' for the same.

```
mButton = (RippleView) findViewById(R.id.btn);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //your code
    }
});
```